# Scrape pics from a website with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I would like to download the profile image from a link.

```
<div class="l-main">
  <script id="js-initial-data" data-json="{"openFanClub":1, "roomId":1700}"> </script>
  <p class="room-profile-head-bg l-room-profile-head-bg">
    <img src="https://image..." alt>
  </p>
</div>
```

Here is my code, but it does not work:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://..."
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,'html.parser')
images = soup.select('script[data-json="{"openFanClub":1, "roomId":1700}"]')
for image in images:
  i = image.attrs['room_id']
  link = image.select_one('img').attrs['src']
  filename = 'images/{i}.jpg'
  print(filename, link)
```

You can use any tool or library (Selenium, BeautifulSoup, etc.) to make it work.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: You've got an error in your selector to start, notice the script data-json="{"
Running your script shows this

    raise SelectorSyntaxError(msg, self.pattern, index)
soupsieve.util.SelectorSyntaxError: Malformed attribute selector at position 6
  line 1:
script[data-json="{"openFanClub":1, "roomId":170038}"]
      ^

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


photos = [170038, 197343, 61730]

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0'
}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for photo in photos:
            print(f"Downloading {photo}.jpg")
            r = req.get(url, params={'room_id': photo}, headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
            target = soup.find("img", width="640").get("src")
            r = req.get(target)
            with open(f"{photo}.jpg", 'wb') as f:
                f.write(r.content)


main("https://www.showroom-live.com/room/profile")
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Anyway, if I want to add more room_id, for example 2 more such as "197343" and "61730" into params, and then get all these 3 images at the same time. The outputs should be "170038.jpg", "197343.jpg" and "197343.jpg". What should I do?

Comment: Or, is it possible to get the list of "room_id" from a DataFrame so that we can download many images at the same time? I would prefer to get the room ids from DataFrame if possible.

Comment: @VNR sure, you can do that. let me update my answer. hold on

Answer (score 0):

You can get the image from the site using this method:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen, urlretrieve

#Get every image from the website
html_page = urlopen('https://www.showroom-live.com/room/profile?room_id=170038')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "html.parser")
images = []
for img in soup.findAll('img'):
    images.append(img.get('src'))

#extract profile image
image = images[5]

#Download Image
path = r"C:\Users\username\Downloads\room_id.jpg"
urlretrieve(image, path)
```

If I understand you correctly, this is more of what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry about the miscommunication. I see you already have an answer so I wont bother to update mine. Yes it did eork on my PC. If you didn't change the string in the path variable then it wouldn't have worked. Also it is getting it automatically not manually.

Comment: Nevermind I see what you mean about getting it automatically, sorry